# Dealing with mixed elements in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe that includes integers, lists of integers, strings, and combinations therein. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, '1, 2, z', 0, 2, '1, z', 'z', 0, 1]})
```

I want to be able to firstly identify the unique elements among these entries, and then to be able to sort by them. The first problem is recognizing the lists as collections of individual elements:

```
print(set(df['A'].values))

{0, 1, 2, '1, 2, z', 'z', '1, z'}
```

where I would ideally like to retrieve here is: {0, 1, 2, z}. I tried splitting the lists along the commas, but this ignores all the integers:

```
df_B = df['A'].str.split(',', expand=True)
print (df_B)

     0     1     2
0  NaN   NaN   NaN
1  NaN   NaN   NaN
2    1     2     z
3  NaN   NaN   NaN
4  NaN   NaN   NaN
5    1     z  None
6    z  None  None
7  NaN   NaN   NaN
8  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I can get around that by first converting everything to strings:

```
df_tmp = df['A'].astype(str)
df_C = df_tmp.str.strip().str.split(',', expand=True)
print (df_C)

   0     1     2
0  0  None  None
1  1  None  None
2  1     2     z
3  0  None  None
4  2  None  None
5  1     z  None
6  z  None  None
7  0  None  None
8  1  None  None

print(set(np.concatenate(df_C.values)))

{'1', ' 2', 'z', None, '2', '0', ' z'}
```

But I still have a problem with white-space despite using str.strip(), so if I now look for occurrences of a particular element like '2', I don't find those with whitespaces:

```
df_keep = df_C.loc[df_C[0] == '2']
print (df_keep)

   0     1     2
4  2  None  None
```

In any case, I wonder if there isn't a better/more efficient way to achieve what I am trying to do than to convert everything to strings and to generate another dataframe with new columns for each element, since I then have to copy the indices into another list to retrieve the information from the corresponding rows of the original dataframe.

Is there a way to search through a mixture of individual elements and lists in the original dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, convert all to string, split, explode and get the set:

```
s = df['A'].astype(str).str.split(',\s*').explode()

out = set(s)
```

output: `{'0', '1', '2', 'z'}`

To keep integers, you could do:

```
s = df['A'].astype(str).str.split(',\s*').explode(ignore_index=True)
s2 = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').dropna().astype(int)
out = set(s.loc[s.index.difference(s2.index)]) | set(s2)
```

output: `{0, 1, 2, 'z'}`

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful for finding the set. But is there a simple way to retrieve the original indices (from the first dataframe) in the second case?